# New to mysql, query throwing wrong syntax

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to pass this query from my Java application but it is saying I have an error in the UPDATE line, but i cant find what is wrong? can you spot see what I am doing wrong?

```
int rs = st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO timesheet (employeeID, statusCode, periodEndingDate, departmentCode, minutesMon,"+
            "minutesTue, minutesWed, minutesThu, minutesFri, minutesSat, minutesSun)"+
            " VALUES ('"+empID+"','"+statusCode+"','"+periodEndingDate+"','"+departmentCode+"','"+minutesMon+"','"+
             minutesTue+"','"+minutesWed+"','"+minutesThu+"','"+minutesFri+"','"+minutesSat+"','"+minutesSun+"')"+
             " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE timesheet SET statusCode='"+statusCode+"', periodEndingDate='"+periodEndingDate+"', departmentCode='"+departmentCode+"',"+
            " minutesMon = '"+minutesMon+"', minutesTue='"+minutesTue+"', minutesWed='"+minutesWed+"', minutesThu='"+minutesThu+"', minutesFri='"+minutesFri+"',"+
            " minutesSat='"+minutesSat+"', minutesSun='"+minutesSun+"' WHERE periodEndingDate='"+periodEndingDate+"' AND employeeID='"+empID+"';");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a `WHERE` clause with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. It is updating the duplicate.
If you have a `UNIQUE` index on `(periodEndingDate, employeeID)`, it is already updating the correct row without the where clause. Also, lose the tablename and the `SET` in the Update clause.

[MySQL Docs on ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: Your welcome! Also, welcome to Stackoverflow. Have a look at the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask), if an answer was helpful you can upvote it or accept it clicking on the green checkbox under the score.